# Updating/merging a document through nested array

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Context: On the client, a field is modified and that change is propagated to the server as a keypath-value pair. I start out with a keypath, something like `foo.bar.baz` = `cat`, which I can convert to `{foo: {bar: {baz: "cat"}}}` and then `merge` into my document (which might look something like `{foo: {bar: {baz: "dog"}}}`).

So far, this has worked fine for all *objects*, however it breaks down when I need to do something with an **array**.

---

Suppose my document in RethinkDB looked like this: `{name: "Me", pets: [{name: "Shadow"}]}`. The user decides to update the pet's name, so the keypath looks something like `pets[0].name` = `Sparky`. As far as I can tell, this can't trivially (or non-trivially, for that matter) be converted into something I can pass to `merge`. Or can it? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to write something like `.update(function(row) { return {pets: row('pets').changeAt(0, row('pets')(0).merge({name: 'Sparky'}))};})`.  I would recommend instead making `pets` a map from names to pets (or from "numbers converted to strings" to pets if you really want indexing).

Comment: Thanks mlucy. I'm going to give the map of numbers-as-strings to values a try. (I'd *like* to keep the "pets" ordered, and if I were to key by name [name-to-value mapping], I'd need to keep track of the order through another array...which I'd need to update if any of the names changed.)

Comment: Alright, what I ended up doing was somewhat grotesque, but this is for a hobby project anyway. I just retrieved the entire object, made the changes I needed, then put the whole thing back (`replace`d the entire document). Simple, relatively easy, and no hacks...other than being non-atomic and rather inefficient.